# Stored procedure not return data while where condition as parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

```
ALTER PROCEDURE procGetData
    @companyid INT,
    @condition NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @cond NVARCHAR
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR

    SELECT @sql = 'select e.id, e.code, e.firstname + isnull('' ''+e.lastname,'''') [name],
                   from hrm_employee e
                   inner join (select max(id) [id], hrm_employeeid from hrm_employeeservice group by hrm_employeeid) ser on ser.hrm_employeeid = e.id
                   inner join hrm_gender g on e.genderid = g.id and g.companyid = '+CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@companyid)+'inner join hrm_maritalstatus m on e.maritalstatusid=m.id and m.companyid='+CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@companyid)+'
                   where '+@cond


    EXEC (@sql)
END
```

The selected values(id,code,name) are not get while exec this stored procedure from C# using sqlAdapter

Comment: `condition` parameter come or not?

Comment: maybe you need  after `where` + `condition`

Comment: Before anything, fix that **huge** injection issue you have. **NEVER** inject unsanitised values into a Dynamic SQL Statement. **NEVER**.

Comment: [Little Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/), [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql). And if you don't believe it, try `EXEC procGetData 1,N'1 = 1; CREATE LOGIN SU WITH PASSWORD = '123', CHECK_POLICY = OFF, CHECK_EXPIRY = OFF; ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER SU; CREATE DATABASE ILiekInjection;';` (and then clean up the mess.)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` / `nvarchar` variables and parameters that you use. In your case, `@sql` is **exactly ONE character** long, since you didn't specify a length - so it will hold the string `s` and **nothing else**!

Comment: Oh, you're right @marc_s , that makes it even *easier* to inject into then... /headdesk (replace `1 = 1;` with `ELECT 1;`)

Answer (score 1):

@cond variable is declared but never assigned and this means that the supplied parameter "@condition" is not used in the stored procedure at all.

It is bad bad practice (SQL Injection) to have where clause passed in as parameter. I completely agree with Larnu & marc_s on the coding practice.